# Diff based coding style inspection?

Tags: coding-style

I'd like to do an automated coding style inspection on changes (to be) committed to the repository.

Is there a tool can do style inspection/static inspection for patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebKit team have a Python-based code review bot that check incoming patches (diffs) for style issues. Perhaps you could adapt that to your needs?

Look at `check-webkit-style` and the `webkitpy` directory in http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Tools/Scripts/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at that. I think I might do style check for both original file and result file and compare the diff.

Comment: I had a look at webkitpy/style. They took the line numbers of the changed lines, and extract only style violation reported on those lines. Roughly the same idea, but more straight forward.